# Zend Studio 9: How do I create a shortcut ?

Tags: zend-studio

I want to create a shortcut inside Zend Studio 9 for a code snippet I have created in the code gallery. How do you create a shortcut. I don't see anything in the user guide nor online.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZS doesn't work with keyboard shortcuts for code snippets/templates. Instead, you can define the templates, and when you start entering the first few letters of that template, the studio will suggest to 'autocomplete' the entire template.

for reference : http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=76228